# Vertex and edge deletion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was given this example. I am wondering how does this work? The question says that G -v where v is a subset of V. From my understanding, this means that we remove perform a vertex deletion on graph G. I do not understand the first two and last two graphs. Those four graphs clearly performed a vertex and edge deletion. In addition, does have 2 same graphs mean anything? Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the vertices of the "center square" are removed, we obtain the following graphs:

[image]
[image]

which are isomorphic to the left two and the right two graphs respectively.

The 2 same graphs appear since the original graph is (rotationally) symmetric: removing the leftmost vertex and removing the rightmost vertex will generate the middle two graphs, which are isomorphic, but are distinct graphs.

The set $\{G-v \mid v\in V\}$ must have the same number of elements as $V$; if the "same" graphs are omitted, this rule will be violated.

Comment: Ohh I see it now, thank you very much. Does the number graph in the corresponding set equivalent to number of vertices in the original graph?

Comment: If you mean "number of graphs", yes.